# Django FastApi 2 servers

Tags: python, django

Please help me. I have a project on Django, in which some of the processes go through celery. But now I want to transfer all the complex data processing to another server. I plan to use FastApi. But the question arose - how to properly organize the work with the client files that will be processed . Do I need to receive files from the client and save them on the second server, or do I need to save them on the first server and send them over tcp? Perhaps there are other options ? How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django-storages .It covers all my needs